# Is Microsoft AD based on an LDAP Spec?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, protocols, specifications

LDAP is a protocol for connecting to and querying Directory Services.

When Microsoft created AD did they design it upon the LDAP specification?

Im trying to understand if AD is based on LDAP in some form to be compatible with LDAP?

OR can LDAP integrate with any backend (within reason) and its the configuration of LDAP that contains the logic in how LDAP connects to the backend Directory Service DB/data store, so that LDAP can be used to query the data stored within it?

I can never seem to find a definitive answer for this question when I read AD/LDAP based articles online.

Comment: It obeys the LDAP protocol, but I believe it violates other LDAP specifications in significant ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

if you want to query ADSI using LDAP port (in any backend program) you can do that without any problem .

also if you want to view it in LDAP type context you can download and install "Softerra LDAP Browser 4.5 " on any windows system that uses ADSI and it will display everything to you like LDAP like "CN=Users,DC=DEMO,DC=COM"
etc

if you need any sample code, do create a question with your specification users will be happy to help you.

More ever connecting to LDAP doesn't require any external libraries if you are using java.
While connecting to ADSI may require COM Components